# Default template argument in method hidden behind class default template argument

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <iostream>

template< typename T = char >
struct Foo {
        void bar();
};

template< typename T = int >
void Foo< T >::bar() {
    std::cout << typeid( T ).name() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Foo<> x1;
    Foo< double > x2;
    x1.bar();
    x2.bar();
}
```

Output:

```
char
double
```

`char` is hiding the `int` here, why is that?

Is it even possible to have multiple different template arguments for the same class?
(Guess not)But why doesn't yell the compiler then?

---

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/892125/ill-formed-default-template-argument-not-throwing-error

Comment: The code will not compile: 'error: default argument for template parameter for class enclosing ‘void Foo<T>::bar()’'

Comment: Mhh, compiles fine for me in Visual Studio 2013 Professional, Debug mode

Comment: g++ 4.7.2 gives the above error

Comment: g++ isn't alone on that regard. clang++ 3.4 likewise pukes on this: "Cannot add a default template argument to the definition of a member of a class template".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### ill-formed snippet

The code provided in your post is ill-formed as stated by the C++ Standard ([n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)):

> `14.1p9` **Template parameters** `[temp.param]`
>
> > A *default template-argument* is a *template-argument* (14.3) specified after `=` in a *template-paraemter*. A default *template-argument* may be specified for any kind of *template-parameter* (type, non-type, template) that is not a template parameter pack (14.5.3). A default *template-argument* may be specified in a template declaration. [ **Note**: **>>**] A default *template-argument* shall not be specified in the *template-parameter-lists* of the definition of a member of a class template that appears outside of the member's class. [ **<<** :**Note** ]

---

#### Conclusion

With the above quotation in mind we can draw the conclusion that the compiler you are using is faulty; it's not conformant to the rules set out by the Standard, the snippet should not be accepted.

---

#### What are the reason behind the Standard disallowing such construct?

Honestly this most probably boils down to *"well, it doesn't make sense to allow it"*.

Since the type of `x1` (and with that the type of `T`) is known at the type of declaration (`Foo<>` *=>* `F<char>`), a potential *default template-argument* when defining a member of the class is useless; it will never be required, nor will it be used.

Comment: So the default template argument type of a member function, here it's `T = int`, will never take effect, right?

Comment: @songyuanyao see updated answer, the previous answer what somewhat misleading.

Comment: I was just about to answer this and saw you had done it almost an hour ago! I though I had gone blind until I realised you just edited your old, deleted answer :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza indeed, the *deleted* answer didn't directly answer what OP is referring to, and instead of posting a new one I edited the old on, and *undeleted* it.

Comment: Thank you. Also your previous answer was a good explanation _why_ this is ill-formed.